# Get Dates for Last Week in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Ok I'm trying to get the dates for the previous week in Python assuming the week starts on Sunday and Ends on Saturday.

Through google and trial and error, I have this:

```
def get_week_days(year, week):
    d = date(year,1,1)
    if(d.weekday()>3):
        d = d+timedelta(7-d.weekday())
    else:
        d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())
    dlt = timedelta(days = (week-1)*7)
    FH_start = d + dlt
    FH_end = d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)
    return FH_start, FH_end

print get_week_days(2018, this_week_int)
```

and that outputs:
`(datetime.date(2018, 3, 5), datetime.date(2018, 3, 11))`

How do I offset it to have the week start on Sunday, or is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one simple version:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta    
def get_week_days(year, week):

    year_start = date(year, 1, 1)

    # the following line assumes your this_week_int starts at 0
    # if this_week_int starts at 1, change to week-2

    week_start = year_start + timedelta(days=-year_start.isoweekday(), weeks=week-1)
    week_end = week_start + timedelta(days=6)

    return week_start, week_end
```

> ```
> get_week_days(2018, 1)
>
> # (datetime.date(2017, 12, 31), datetime.date(2018, 1, 6))
>
> get_week_days(2018, 10)
>
> # (datetime.date(2018, 3, 4), datetime.date(2018, 3, 10))
> ```

Essentially, `.isoweekday()` returns 1 for Monday and 7 for Sundays, so when you deduct that weekday it gives you the start at Sunday.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can go as follows:

```
from datetime import timedelta
def week_range(date):
   year, week, dow = date.isocalendar()
   # Find the first day of the week.
   if dow == 7:
      # Since we want to start with Sunday, let's test for that condition.
       start_date = date
   else:
    # Otherwise, subtract `dow` number days to get the first day
       start_date = date - timedelta(dow)

    # Now, add 6 for the last day of the week (i.e., count up to Saturday)
   end_date = start_date + timedelta(6)

   return (start_date, end_date)
```

Now you have start and end date of week you can find out week dates as you want. For more you can refer [this](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/calculate-week-range-date/)